# Chrome not recomputing element width when it should

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need to size an element's width with respect to its height and thought I had worked out a pretty clever solution using the transparent `img` trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yc8a2yj/

The pink colored div correctly renders at a 1:2 ratio; however, it is supposed to resize when the viewport does (since it has height 100% of a 100vh element), but it doesn't.

If you resize the viewport, the `img` element increases width if the viewport height increases, but the `container` element does not grow in width to accommodate it, which is violating the rules for what `display: inline-block` means (if you check and uncheck the display style on `.container` in Chrome Console, it will resize properly to fit its child contents). I assume the problem is element dimension calculations are parent to child and thus when the `img` element resizes, Chrome does not recompute it's parents dimensions. Is there a way to trick it into doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome minimizes relayout cycles. And that's good in general.

Instead of `.viewport` I would suggest to set `height:50vh` on image itself and use `width:max-content;` on .container.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/0jgo5894/1/

And about vh units in general: http://sciter.com/css-vwvhvminvmax-units-are-quite-dangerous/